# Is it possible to use the content of a variable in an regexp_like as the source column in Oracle

Tags: oracle, if-statement, regexp-like

I want to compare the contents of table with regex pattern and column_name which is saved as variable in a procedure. Regexp_like with variables v_column_name, v_column_regexp are then in the if statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TBL_COLUMN_REGEX (
    p_data       IN VARCHAR2,
    p_table_name   IN VARCHAR2)
AS
    v_data       VARCHAR2 (50);
    v_table_name   VARCHAR2 (200);
    v_column_name     VARCHAR2 (100);
    v_column_regexp   VARCHAR2 (100);
    v_row_rownum      NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_data := p_data;
    v_table_name := p_table_name;


    FOR i
        IN (SELECT column_name, t1.column_type, column_regexp
              FROM T_TBL_COLUMN  t1
                   INNER JOIN t_column_regexp t2
                       ON t1.column_type = t2.column_type
             WHERE data = v_data AND table_name = v_table_name)
    LOOP
        v_column_name := i.column_name;
        v_column_regexp := i.column_regexp;

        INSERT INTO T_LOG_TBL_COLUMN (DATA, TABLE_NAME, LOG_TEXT)
                 VALUES (  v_data,  v_table_name,  v_column_name  || ' REGEXP Check starts with '  || v_column_regexp);


        FOR r_row IN (SELECT v_column_name, ROWNUM FROM T_TEST)
        LOOP
            v_row_rownum := r_row.ROWNUM;

            IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE (v_column_name,  v_column_regexp)--v_column_name:='DATE' with content as '202311', v_column_regexp:='^\d{4}(0[1-9]|1[012])$'
            THEN
                INSERT INTO T_LOG_TBL_COLUMN (DATA,
                                                 TABLE_NAME,
                                                 LOG_TEXT)
                         VALUES ( v_data, v_table_name,   'In '|| v_row_rownum || ': ' || v_column_name);
            
                COMMIT;
            END IF;

            COMMIT;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

It doesn't match in the if statement, even though I get a match if I use regexp_like in a select statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT rownum, DATE
  FROM T_TEST
 WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (DATE, '^\d{4}(0[1-9]|1[012])$')
```

```
1   202311
2   202311
3   202311
4   202311
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query `SELECT v_column_name, ROWNUM FROM T_TEST_4` will get the literal value of the variable (i.e. the column *name*) for every row in your table, not the column *value*.

You can see that in this simplified demo:

```
declare
  v_column_name all_tab_columns.column_name%type := 'DUMMY';
begin
  for r_row in (select v_column_name as col from dual)
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r_row.col);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

```
dbms_output:
DUMMY
```

It's showing the column name, DUMMY, not the value, X.

If you use a dynamic SQL cursor loop then you get the value instead:

```
declare
  v_column_name all_tab_columns.column_name%type := 'DUMMY';
  v_cursor sys_refcursor;
  v_value varchar2(4000);
begin
  open v_cursor for 'select "' || v_column_name || '" from dual';
  loop
    fetch v_cursor into v_value;
    exit when v_cursor%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_value);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

```
dbms_output:
X
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ACX2wMiD)

You can adapt your code to do the same thing; add variable declarations for the cursor and results:

```
    v_cursor sys_refcursor;
    v_column_value varchar2(4000);
    v_rownum number;
```

and change your loop from:

```
        FOR r_row IN (SELECT v_column_name, ROWNUM FROM T_TEST_4)
        LOOP
            v_row_rownum := r_row.ROWNUM;

            IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE (v_column_name,  v_column_regexp)
...
```

to

```
        OPEN v_cursor FOR 'SELECT "' || v_column_name || '", ROWNUM FROM T_TEST_4';
        LOOP
            FETCH v_cursor INTO v_column_value, v_row_rownum;
            EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;

            IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE (v_column_value, v_column_regexp)
...
```

and presumably change `v_column_name` to `v_column_value` when you insert into your log table too. (You probably don't want to be committing after every insert...)

Comment: Thanks, that works. 
Is it also possible to get the value of v_exttable_name and add it like this

`OPEN v_cursor FOR 'SELECT "' || v_column_name || '", ROWNUM FROM "' ||v_exttable_name '"';`

I am getting this Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
Is it not possible or is it maybe a syntax error?

Comment: I included the double quotes around the column name because that's safer when getting values from the data dictionary, just in case there are quoted identifiers (e.g. mixed-case). That might not be necessary (or desirable) if you're querying your own look-up table. If you quote the `"' ||v_exttable_name '"` too then that has to match the case of the table name in the data dictionary too; again might not be useful or desirable, *unless* you have quoted identifiers, so you can probably just remove the `"` here.